# How to access popup elements using Selenium in Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, firefox, webdriver

I am trying to get and access the elements from a pop-up/alert using selenium in java. Here is the code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Test {


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path_to_gecko_driver");

    FirefoxDriver firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver();

    firefoxDriver.get("some_url_which_needs_webcam_and_microphone");        
    WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(firefoxDriver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(new By.ByClassName("button_id")));
    element.click();

    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) firefoxDriver;
    String title = String.valueOf(js.executeScript("return document.title"));

    System.out.println("Title ==== " + title);

    Object rezult = js.executeScript("return document.getElementById(\'nav-bar\')");
    System.out.println("Browser element ==== " + rezult); //===>null

    System.out.println("FINISH");

    }
}
```

I am trying to access the browser pop-up elements, so I can choose between the available webcams or microphones and allow or deny the access. The JS code works just fine in the browser's console, but not in Java.

Any time I try to access any element in Java by using the JavascriptExecutor the element is null.

How can I access the pop-up elements by using the JavascriptExecutor in Java? Are there any other predefined configs or any other prerequisites that I am missing? Thank you

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? At which line? What does the error says? Update the Question with error stack trace.

Comment: This one:  js.executeScript("return document.getElementById(\'nav-bar\')"); Here the result is null when compiling in Java, and not in the browser console. This is a browser element as well

Comment: You can use alert class to handle alert in browser

Comment: @Ankur. I've already did that. The result is also null

Comment: I am using a Maven project with selenium-java 3.8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are invoking `click()` prior to this action we should induce `WebDriverWait` for the `WebElement` identified as **`getElementById('nav-bar')`** to render properly through **`ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable`** and try the following :

```
js.executeScript("return document.getElementById('nav-bar')");
```

Comment: Already done that too, I've escaped the " ' " character because I've thought that could be the problem. Thank you